# JQuery Mobile equivalent to Android ViewPager

Tags: jquery-mobile

On Android, the ViewPager allows multiple pages of content to be seen with the same layout.  Typically, a person swipes left and right to navigate through the pages. Is there an equivalent of this in JQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about pagination: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/

Comment: thanks.  the jqm docs advise using a single-page that can call other pages.  in our case, each page is identical wrt markup and function, only the content changes between pages.  the other requirement is that the number of pages is undefined ie. in a session, a person can swipe through to N pages where N is not known beforehand.  I thought that there must be a standard JQM construct that would satisfy our requirement as it is very much like an ebook reader function?

Comment: Mh. I don't think something like this is available out-of-the-box. Have you tought about making a pagination carousel = previous-current-next page and dynamically updating contents with the JQM 1.2 fetchlink feature (in-the-works-link: http://jquerymobile.com/branches/fetchlink/docs/pages/page-fetchlinks.html) This way you would only need 3 containers, which the user goes merry-go-round and depending on the page he goes to you pull in contents using fetchlink on pagebeforechange(?). Would also be nice in terms of keeping the DOM compact.

Comment: which is the way the android viewpager works by keeping 3 pages (left, current, right) dynamically available.  okay, have enough to get going with.  strange that this functionality is not available out-of-the-JQM-box because it is used/needed very frequently in apps.

Comment: if you get it working be sure to post back :-). Would be a handy tool. Also post your pagination questions, I've been fiddling with it quite a bit.